# When I use basemap in python, longitude is sometimes reversed, flipping the map

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, matplotlib-basemap

In python, I use basemap (https://matplotlib.org/basemap/) for plotting spatial data, and I've used it for several years without any large problems.  I recently had to reinstall python3 (through conda, along with a number of modules) and basemap now has a strange issue: under certain conditions, the map will be displayed with flipped longitudes, switching east and west.  As an example, I use this code: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/robin.html.  If I use that code as-is, the map displays fine, but when I set lon_0=180, the map gets flipped, as shown in the image below.

[Image of map problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTvR9.jpg)

Setting lon_0 to any positive number results in a flipped map, while 0 or negative numbers result in a correct map.  lon_0 should simply set the central longitude of the plotted map, and should not have this behavior, so I'm unsure what's going on.  Has anyone seen this behavior before, or have suggestions for how to fix it?  I could alter my code to work around it, but I'd rather have things work properly.

I am using python3.7.3.  I've tried updating basemap with the command "conda install -c anaconda basemap", but it tells me that basemap is up to date already.

Here is the code.  It is identical to the code linked above, but with lon_0 set to 180.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# lon_0 is central longitude of projection.
# resolution = 'c' means use crude resolution coastlines.
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=180,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
plt.title("Robinson Projection")
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, the only output is this, which seems unrelated:

map_test.py:36: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The dedent function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use inspect.cleandoc instead.
  m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=180,resolution='c')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem. Just add this after creating the axes:

```py
# Matplotlib >= 3.1.0 (introduced "set_inverted")
ax.xaxis.set_inverted(False)

# Matplotlib < 3.1.0 (this is just the source code for "set_inverted")
interval = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()
ax.set_xlim(sorted(interval), auto=None)
```

After some trial and error it also seems that selecting a *negative* central longitude instead of positive longitude works:

```py
m = Basemap('robin', lon_0=-180)
```

Comment: Great, this solved the problem.  I didn't try the <3.1.0 version, but the >=3.1.0 version worked.   I was initially confused by the "self" keyword, but I simply replaced "self" with the variable name for my axes, which was "ax".  Thanks!

Comment: Np! Sorry for the confusion, just cleaned up my answer